# « Il existe » vs « il y a »

Tags: sens, expressions, usage, expressions-idiomatiques

Quelles sont les différences majeures entre **il y a** et **il existe** ?

Dans quels cas peut-on les utiliser indifféremment ?

Dans quels cas ne peut-on pas employer l'un à la place de l'autre ?

Comment: Attention : Au sens de *il y a*, *il existe* est invariable. (Pas de pluriel.)

Comment: Merci ! Je viens d'éditer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La même différence qu'entre *être* et *exister*.

Benveniste a longuement analysé ce "*y a*" qu'il rapproche du verbe *être* tel qu'analysé par Aristote.
*Il y a* = *Il est*

On peut aussi d'ailleurs entendre utilisé "*il **est** des xyzt*" dans très exactement le même sens que *"il **y a** des xyzt"*

Tu noteras au passage que le *il* utilisé ici est le pronom impersonnel. (=> jamais de passage à la 3e personne du pluriel)

On observera au demeurant qu'impersonnel, ce sujet ne sert pas à grand chose puisque il a tendance à ne même plus se dire, même chez les "bons" auteurs :

*Y a bien des gens qui sont débarqués de cette façon-là* (Céline)

En résumé donc : y a = il y a = il est.
*Il existe* dit sensiblement la même chose avec la nuance que tu mets entre *être* et *exister*.

Comment: « y a » est de la langue parlée relâchée et doit être évité; « il est » appartient à la langue littéraire et ne peut être utilisé dans la langue parlée que dans la conversation assez formelle ou dont le ton est solennel; il n'est pas question de dire par exemple « Il est des spaghettis dans le placard et il est de la sauce tomate aussi, fais-toi des spaghettis. ».   Dans le parler ordinaire, mais standard on ne dit que « il y a ». On peut demander à quoi sert le y aussi; réponse: (à rien).